# foursquare api venue details specialsnearby not being returned

Tags: foursquare

When making a Foursquare venue details API call, the specialsNearby field does not exist in the json response. I have tried hundreds of different venues, and none of them contain this field (they do contain the 'specials' field though).

I'm using v2 of the foursquare API, and giving it a version string of v=20120417.

Any assistance in obtaining the nearby specials would be much appreciated!

Comment: It is also not working for me at the moment. It seems like the field has been removed or is not outputted at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like we've stopped sending down the specialsNearby field -- once I can confirm with a few of the other dev's, we'll update the docs accordingly.

**Edit:** We have indeed deprecated this field in favor of the Explore endpoint below.

But, no need to worry -- there's an easy way to get the same info!

Check out our Explore endpoint -- https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore

Pass "intent=specials" to that endpoint, and you'll get all the nearby specials.